# Copying from exfat microsd card freezes my PC

Tags: usb, exfat

I've installed exfat-fuse exfat-utils in order to read an exfat microsd card which is plugged via USB adapter. It reads fine and copies but after a while it freezes the whole system.

I ctrl+alt+F3 switch to a terminal and kill all nautilius related processes but that doesn't help.
Only when I unplug the usb adapter it unfreezes shortly after.

Comment: 1. Can you copy a single file? Please try first with a small file, and later with a big file; 2. Have you checked (in Windows), if the exfat file system is good (not corrupted)? 3. Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: 1.Yes, actually I managed to copy about 2gb of files. It might be actually copying while the pc is freezed for user input, not sure.
2. Don't have windows so can't check
3. 18.04.1

Comment: I am running 18.04.1 and it works to read/write via USB. But I have seen cases, when there are problems with many files, while it is possible to write to and read from a tar archive. So I suggest that you try to read from the card and write into a tarfile, with something like `sudo tar -cvf $HOME/test-tarfile .` when the current directory is a directory with many [and big] files in the card. Please try and let us know the result.